# Hibernate primitive collection contains value

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Given a hibernate mapping like this:

```
<class name="TestData" table="test_data">
    <id name="integer" column="id_column"/>
    <bag name="integers" table="test_data_collection">
        <key column="id_column"/>
        <element column="value" type="integer"/>
    </bag>
</class>
```

How can I create a Criteria that will create SQL something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test_data WHERE 100 in (SELECT value FROM test_data_collection WHERE test_data_collection.id_column=test_data.id_column)
```

The goal being to get all TestData objects which have 100 in their 'integers' list. Ideally, I'd like to do the reverse too: all TestData objects which *don't* have 100 in their 'integers' list.

Most searching online showed examples of this when the bag contains objects, but I can't figure out how to do it for primitive collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via a sub query.

```
session.createCriteria(TestData.class)  
        .createAlias("integers", "i")  
        .add(Restrictions.eq("i.value", 100))
        .list();
```

Comment: This works if you add `setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)` since this uses a join, multiple rows for each entity is returned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as a subquery with the current Hibernate Criteria API.

This bug report kind of covers it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-869

You can query this way reasonably with the accepted answer bradleyfitz posted, but you cannot do the inverse (IE not in) because if a collection has [1, 2] and you do `Restrictions.ne("i.value", 1)` then that 2 in the collection returns true and the entity will be in the result set.